# How do I only display the newest added element of an array from an input field

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I am writing a program which is meant to allow you to add parts to a queue, and then display the parts in a separate div tag.  I only want to display the newest added item from the array so that the user can see exactly what part they are working with.

I have already tried setting the part display to only show a particular index such as [0]. But that is only the first index of the array and will not be overwritten by any newly added item.

Here is my code for those who are interested.

```js
var p = "";

let parts = [{
    "Type": "gear",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 5,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "Type": "screw",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 1,
    "Thickness": 1
  },
  {
    "Type": "tube",
    "Width": 3,
    "Length": 8,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "socket",
    "Width": 10,
    "Length": 3,
    "Thickness": 5
  }
];

let queue = [];

function queuePart() {
  p = document.getElementById("parts").value;
  queue.push(p);
  //Display items added to queue.
  document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = queue;
  if (queue.length > 4) {
    queue.shift();
  }
  //Display newest added item to queue in parts display.
  document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = queue[0];
}

let compPart = [];

function completePart() {
  p = document.getElementById("parts").value;
  compPart.push(p);
  queue.shift();
  //Display the first few completed parts from queue.
  document.getElementById("compDisp").innerHTML = compPart;

  function removeAllText(element) {
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var node = nodes[i];
      if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        i--;
      } else if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        removeAllText(node);
      }
    }
  }
  var disp = document.getElementById("disp");
  removeAllText(disp);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Machine Web UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="display" id="screen1">
    <h1>Queue Area</h1>
    <pre id="arr">Currently No Parts In Queue</pre>
    <input type="text" id="parts"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="queuePart()"> Add a Part </button>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen2">
    <h1>Part Display Area</h1>
    <pre id="disp"></pre>
    <button type="button" onclick="completePart()"> Complete Part </button>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen3">
    <h1>Completed Parts Area</h1>
    <pre id="compDisp">Currently no parts completed</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen4">
    <h1>Log Area</h1>
    <pre id="logList"> </pre>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you can use slice(-1) to get lastest one item, like below: ```document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = queue.slice(-1);```

Comment: Try queue.unshift(),, The unshift() method adds new elements to the beginning of an array.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing last item in array**

You can get the latest item in an array, by accessing the length and subtracting 1 (since indexes are 0-based).

```
queue[queue.length-1];
```

or you can use the `at` function with a negative index. [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at)

```
queue.at(-1);
```

**Removing last item in array**

If you want to remove the last element of an array you can do it with the `pop` method. [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
queue.pop();
```

**Side notes**

I improved your snippet formatting.
You can save references to html elements in constants, instead of using `document.getElementById` all the time.

```
const partsInput = document.getElementById("parts");
```

**Snippet**

I took liberties that hopefully align with what you want to achieve.

- The input gets cleared after getting added, and it automatically
  takes focus.
- I removed the removeAllText function since I did not
  find it useful you can clear text by just adding a new value or
  innerHtml of empty string.

```js
var p = "";

let parts = [{
    "Type": "gear",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 5,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "Type": "screw",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 1,
    "Thickness": 1
  },
  {
    "Type": "tube",
    "Width": 3,
    "Length": 8,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "socket",
    "Width": 10,
    "Length": 3,
    "Thickness": 5
  }
];

let queue = [];
let compPart = [];

const partsInput = document.getElementById("parts");
const arrDisplay = document.getElementById("arr");
const completeDisplay = document.getElementById("compDisp");
const newestDisplay = document.getElementById("disp");


function queuePart() {
  queue.push(partsInput.value);
  partsInput.value = ''; //Clear input when added
  partsInput.focus(); //Focuses input
  if (queue.length > 4) {
    queue.shift();
  }
  arrDisplay.innerHTML = queue;
  newestDisplay.innerHTML = queue.at(-1); //Or queue[queue.length-1];
}

function completePart() {
  if (queue.length == 0) return; //Do nothing if queue is empty
  
  compPart.push(queue.pop());
  completeDisplay.innerHTML = compPart;
  arrDisplay.innerHTML = queue;

  if (queue.length > 0) {
    newestDisplay.innerHTML = queue.at(-1); //Or queue[queue.length-1];
  } else {
    newestDisplay.innerHTML = 'Currently No Parts In Queue';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Machine Web UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="display" id="screen1">
    <h1>Queue Area</h1>
    <pre id="arr">Currently No Parts In Queue</pre>
    <input type="text" id="parts"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="queuePart()"> Add a Part </button>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen2">
    <h1>Part Display Area</h1>
    <pre id="disp"></pre>
    <button type="button" onclick="completePart()"> Complete Part </button>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen3">
    <h1>Completed Parts Area</h1>
    <pre id="compDisp">Currently no parts completed</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="display" id="screen4">
    <h1>Log Area</h1>
    <pre id="logList"> </pre>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to ONLY display the last item in your array stack in the ***Parts Display*** section, you can use `arr.length-1` to get the **last** item regardless of the length of the array.

***NOTE:*** *Keep in mind, if you are adding your items to the front of the array using `unshift` then simply getting the first item using `array[0]` would work. However, since you are using `.push()`, which adds the item to the **end**, you need to get the **last** item added using **`arr.length-1`***

Let me know if this is not what your looking for and I can edit or remove this answer.

```js
var p = "";

let parts = [{
    "Type": "gear",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 5,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "Type": "screw",
    "Width": 2,
    "Length": 1,
    "Thickness": 1
  },
  {
    "Type": "tube",
    "Width": 3,
    "Length": 8,
    "Thickness": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "socket",
    "Width": 10,
    "Length": 3,
    "Thickness": 5
  }
];

let queue = [];

function queuePart() {
  p = document.getElementById("parts").value;
  queue.push(p);
  //Display items added to queue.
  document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = queue;
  if (queue.length > 4) {
    queue.shift();
  }
  //Display newest added item to queue in parts display.
  document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = queue[queue.length - 1];
}

let compPart = [];

function completePart() {
  p = document.getElementById("parts").value;
  compPart.push(p);
  queue.shift();
  //Display the first few completed parts from queue.
  document.getElementById("compDisp").innerHTML = compPart;


  function removeAllText(element) {


    var nodes = element.childNodes;

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

      var node = nodes[i];


      if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {

        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);


        i--;

      } else


      if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        removeAllText(node);

      }
    }
  }
  var disp = document.getElementById("disp");
  removeAllText(disp);
}
```

```html
<div class="display" id="screen1">
  <h1>Queue Area</h1>
  <pre id="arr">Currently No Parts In Queue</pre>
  <input type="text" id="parts"></input>
  <button type="button" onclick="queuePart()"> Add a Part </button>
</div>
<div class="display" id="screen2">
  <h1>Part Display Area</h1>
  <pre id="disp"></pre>
  <button type="button" onclick="completePart()"> Complete Part </button>
</div>
<div class="display" id="screen3">
  <h1>Completed Parts Area</h1>
  <pre id="compDisp">Currently no parts completed</pre>
</div>
<div class="display" id="screen4">
  <h1>Log Area</h1>
  <pre id="logList"> </pre>
</div>
```